# Buttons reloaded to the page from an AJAX call, click events do not function

Tags: jquery, event-handling

This is an ASP.NET Core web application using .NET 7.
I have a page where I am creating Notes, and once the note is created, it dynamically loads all the Notes for that symbol in a table under the form.

Here is the HTML section

```
<section>
<div id="error-messages" class="text-danger hidden"></div>
<table id="notes-for-symbol-table"
       class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">Symbol</th>
            <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" style="width: 10%;">Date</th>
            <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" style="width: 10%; font-size: .618em;">Author-Source</th>
            <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" style="width: 50%;">Text</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">Moves</th>
            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="notes-for-symbol-body">
    </tbody>
</table>
</section>
```

The rows are generated dynamically via an AJAX call:

```
const getEquityNotesForSymbol = async function (symbol) {
    var newHtml = "";
    try {
        const responseData = await $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: `${apiBaseUrl}/notes/${symbol}`,
            datatype: "json"
        });

        $.each(responseData, function (i, item) {
            newHtml = `${newHtml} <tr><td class="text-center">${item.partitionKey}
            </td><td class="fw-semibold fs-sm">${item.rowKey}
            </td><td class="d-none d-md-table-cell fs-sm">${item.noteAuthor} - ${item.noteSource}
            </td><td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">${item.noteText}
            </td><td class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">Net: ${item.netChangeOnDayOfNote}<br />Pct:
            ${item.percentChangeOnDayOfNote}</td><td class="text-center">
            <button class="btn fas fa-edit" style="color:orange"
            onclick="editEquityNote(${item.partitionKey}, ${item.rowKey})"></button>
            <button class="btn fas fa-trash-alt" style="color:red"
            onclick="deleteEquityNote(${item.partitionKey}, ${item.rowKey})"></button>
            </td></tr>`;
        });

        const $notesTable = $("#notes-for-symbol-table > tbody");
        $notesTable.html("");
        $notesTable.html(newHtml);
       //rest removed for brevity
```

The dynamically created edit and delete buttons do not function. I'm certain that this is normal after reading about delegated events. From what I read, you have to use a parent selector that already exists in the HTML and then drill down to the dynamically created part.

I am not sure how to create this type of delegated event handler. Do I do it in the onclick event in the button HTML? Do I create a function in the .js file? I am a low-end/intermediate user of jQuery and JavaScript, so I am not familiar with how to use and create these delegated events handlers.

Comment: I don't think [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is necessarily the solution here. Your inline functions will work as long as they are defined globally. When you say that the buttons "do not function", what Error are you getting?

Comment: No error, I only have an alert in the inline function right now. It is not getting called getting called.  But I now have a delegated event with the tbody parent that IS getting called. So Ill work with that unless you have a better solution.

Comment: I think that's great if you have a delegated event handler that is working. Just for the sake of being thorough, I wanted to show that the inline function calls can work, but you may need to add quotes around the interpolated arguments (if they are strings). See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/xqwgd4s2/

Comment: Well "works" is a relative term. I can enter the delegated function from clicking the trash or edit icon, but I can't seem to get the data I want, even if I add data-partitionKey and data-rowKey attributes. I tried switching to your inline method but when I click the icon, my breakpoint at the alert isn't hit in the function

Comment: I got it working (I was missing the single quotes around the partitionKey) thanks. Post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) could work in your scenario, but it wouldn't fix anything inherent to using inline functions as you are doing with your `editEquityNote` and `deleteEquityNote` `onclick` handlers. As long as those functions are defined in the global scope, then they will be accessible when those buttons are clicked, regardless of when those buttons were added to the DOM.

However, I suspect (and you have confirmed in the comments) that there is an issue with how you are passing your arguments to these inline function invocations. A template string like `onclick="editEquityNote(${item.partitionKey}, ${item.rowKey})"`, when given an item like `{ partitionKey: 1, rowKey: 'ABC' }`, will result in the interpolated string: `onclick="editEquityNote(1, ABC)"`. This is invalid JavaScript because a string like `ABC` needs to be surrounded by quotes. In order to get the intended and valid interpolation, we would need to include quotes in our template string around `${item.rowKey}`: `onclick="editEquityNote(${item.partitionKey}, '${item.rowKey}')"`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/xqwgd4s2/) is an example fiddle.

This change should be enough to get things working, but for the sake of completeness, I will demonstrate how you would use Event Delegation in your scenario.

You would need to add data-attributes containing the `partitionKey` and `rowKey` values so that your delegated click handler can access these values from the clicked element. You will also need a way to differentiate Edit buttons from Delete buttons with a jQuery selector. I will use data-attributes for this as well: `[data-edit-button]` for the Edit button and `[data-delete-button]` for the Delete button. The relevant section of the template becomes:

```
<button
  class="btn fas fa-edit"
  style="color:orange"
  data-edit-button
  data-partition-key="${item.partitionKey}"
  data-row-key="${item.rowKey}"
>Edit</button>
<button
  class="btn fas fa-trash-alt"
  style="color:red"
  data-delete-button
  data-partition-key="${item.partitionKey}"
  data-row-key="${item.rowKey}"
>Delete</button>
```

The delegated event handlers will need to be attached to element that already exists in the DOM, we can use the `#notes-for-symbol-table` table for that. The handlers are:

```
$('#notes-for-symbol-table').on('click', '[data-edit-button]', function () {
  const $this = $(this);
  const partitionKey = $this.data('editPartitionKey');
  const rowKey = $this.data('rowKey');
  
  alert(`edit: partitionKey = ${partitionKey}, rowKey = ${rowKey}`);
});

$('#notes-for-symbol-table').on('click', '[data-delete-button]', function () {
  const $this = $(this);
  const partitionKey = $this.data('editPartitionKey');
  const rowKey = $this.data('rowKey');
  
  alert(`delete: partitionKey = ${partitionKey}, rowKey = ${rowKey}`);
});
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/0mk4buqL/) is a fiddle for this example.